# Phabricator clone The requested URL returned error: 500

Tags: git, phabricator

I created a git repo on Phabricator and intended to clone via HTTP:
I get the message:

```
Cloning into 'test'...
fatal: unable to access 'http://XXX.XXX.XXX/diffusion/T/test.git/': The requested URL returned error: 500
```

Many thanks in advance
[image]

[image]

in my  /etc/sudoers

```
Defaults        env_reset
Defaults        requiretty  ## 
Defaults        mail_badpass
Defaults        secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"


git ALL=(dev) SETENV: NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/git-upload-pack, /usr/bin/git-receive-pack, /usr/bin/hg, /usr/bin/svnserve
www-data ALL=(dev) SETENV: NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/git-upload-pack, /usr/lib/git-core/git-http-backend, /usr/bin/hg
```

Answer (score 0):

Please follow https://secure.phabricator.com/T10228 for more information. We're adding additional debugging tools to Phabricator to help isolate these issues.